# Find array duplicates, add to the original and then delete

Tags: php, arrays, function

When a duplicate is found in URL I want to:

1. Take 'score' and add it to the original
2. Take 'engine' string and append it to the original
3. Then delete the entire duplicate entry

> ```
> array
>   0 => 
>     array
>       'url' => string 'http://blahhotel.com/'
>       'score' => int 1
>       'engine' => string 'cheese'
>   1 => 
>     array
>       'url' => string 'http://www.blahdvd.com/'
>       'score' => int 2
>       'engine' => string 'cheese'
>   2 => 
>     array
>       'url' => string 'http://blahhotel.com/'
>       'score' => int 1
>       'engine' => string 'pie'
>   3 => 
>     array
>       'url' => string 'http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blah'
>       'score' => int 2
>       'engine' => string 'pie'
>   4 => 
>     array
>       'url' => string 'http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blah'
>       'score' => int 1
>       'engine' => string 'apples'
> ```

It should look like this in the end:

> ```
> array
>   0 => 
>     array
>       'url' => string 'http://blahhotel.com/'
>       'score' => int 2
>       'engine' => string 'cheese, pie'
>   1 => 
>     array
>       'url' => string 'http://www.blahdvd.com/'
>       'score' => int 2
>       'engine' => string 'cheese'
>   3 => 
>     array
>       'url' => string 'http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blah'
>       'score' => int 3
>       'engine' => string 'pie, apples'
> ```

Comment: tried to do nothing and failed ?

Comment: I've been working at it for hours. I will include my code snippets but it will probably be of no help. I will keep this updated with my progress. No need to be snarky. Thank you.

Comment: You might be surprised. Perhaps your code is close, but someone could spot a subtle error. If so, it would save time. Regardless, it would show that you have made a genuine attempt. Also, this is otherwise a very clear question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've been trying so many things and deleting/commenting as I go. I was completely stuck. I will note for future. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries. I just wanted to let you know that, despite a little criticism, you have a good question.

Comment: I got flamed before for not making the question clear and ended up deleting it! So I wanted to make sure I had that nailed! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this meets your requirements.

Based on the desired output you provided, it appeared that you wanted to preserve the numeric indices of each entry. If you don't actually need to preserve those numbers, you can remove the second `foreach` loop and the lines regarding the `$indices` variable, then just return `$tmpList`.

```
function reduceEntries($entries)
{
    $tmpList = array();
    $indices = array();

    foreach ($entries as $i => $entry) {
        if (isset($tmpList[$entry['url']])) {
            $tmpList[$entry['url']]['score'] += $entry['score'];
            $tmpList[$entry['url']]['engine'] .= ', ' . $entry['engine'];
        } else {
            $tmpList[$entry['url']] = $entry;
            $indices[$entry['url']] = $i;
        }
    }

    // rebuild final array with indices
    $finalList = array();
    foreach ($tmpList as $url => $entry) {
        $finalList[$indices[$url]] = $entry;
    }

    return $finalList;
}
```

*(Here's [a working example](http://codepad.org/mDpAwWeZ) on codepad.)*